# Yii calculate model value

Tags: php, yii

Ok, I have a problem with my Yii models. I have a 1: m relationship between the tables "besuch" and "note".

Note:

```
id_note    note    wertung    besuch_id 
   1        4        0.5         1
   2        5         1          1
   3        4.5       2          1
```

besuch:

```
id_besuch   user_id   fach_id    ...
    1          1         1
```

Now I want to create a gridview of the "besuch". In this gridview one column should be "average". This average is calculated like this:

```
average = all(note.note * note.wertung) / Sum(note.wertung) 

where id_besuch = besuch_id
```

Example:

```
average = (4 * 0.5 + 5 * 1 + 4.5 * 2) / 0.5 + 1 + 2 = 
16 / 3.5 = 
4.571...
```

Now I would like to implement this function into my gridView like this:

```
array(
    'name' => 'average',
    'value' => '$data->average'
),
```

I know that this is just an abstract representation of what i want.

Has someone a good idea or can someone say where i need to implement a funciton like this?

thanks

Comment: do you need to calculate average for all notes related to besuch?

Comment: Yes, i tried to scho this with the where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok if i understood your problem then you can do like this.

1. First make a function in your model besuch like

> ```
> public function calculateAverage($id)
> {
>     $numerator=0;
>     $denominator=0;
>     $notes=Note::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('besuch_id'=>$id));
>     foreach($notes as $note)
>     {
>         $numerator=$numerator+($note->note*$note->wertung);
>         $denominator=$denominator+$note->note;
>     }
>     $result=$numerator/$denominator;
>     return $result;
> }
> ```

Now in your grid you can us it as

```
array(
    'header' => 'Average',
    'value' => '$data->calculateAverage($data->id)'
),
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this as soon as I can.

Comment: ok, do let me know, but you may need some changes according to your model. like i have passed $data->id to function but you may need to pass a different parameter. I dont know exactly the attribute names.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem, thanks. I will let you know wenn i tried it.